# Can Descent demons sense Fallen demons and vice versa?

Tags: world-of-darkness, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, conversion, demon-the-descent, demon-the-fallen

With the [*Demon Translation Guide*](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/151502/Demon-Translation-Guide) out now there is the ability to combine both fallen and descent demons in hybrid settings.

One question that popped up though is:
Does Aetheric Resonance register fallen demons? And does the Supernatural Awareness of the fallen react to Aetheric Resonance? Essentially, how do the sense powers of the two splats react to the other splat?

Answer (score 8):

While I haven't seen this translation guide, I can safely assume it follows other guides between oWoD and nWoD - which is changing old *splat* into new *splat*, not into new kind of *splat*.

So when you use this guide, you combine both D:tF and D:tD creatures into exactly same thing, so you won't have two kinds of creatures (one opposing Abrahamic God, one escaping from the Machine) but simple unified Demons, opposing the whatever you do with God-Machine. So if fallen demon can detect other fallen demon and descended demon can detect other descended demon then fallen one can detect descended one, because fallen demon=descended demon.
QED.

Comment: This fits the tagline in the Guide's description: “**What if the God-Machine was just...God?**” You could use that as circumstantial evidence.

Comment: There are a few scenarios presented inside where they are different things. The descent demons for example the "childs" of an alien god who sent the god machine to transform earth while it itself battles with the abrahamic god. And the fallen the "childs" of the abrahamic god.

Comment: Thats because in the end its a guide: do-it-yourself kind of book. You can say for example (following Gnostic) that God-Machine is Demiurg (creator of imperfect physical word) and God is the true "perfect" God and demons have different origins or that Abrahamic God evolved into Machine and Fallen came from "beta" version of angels. But in the end they all follow the same mechanics, so they are the same thing. But as always, Storyteller has the last word.

Answer (score 3):

## It's up to you

The translation guides are, at their core, home-brew suggestions.  You, the ST, have to fill in a lot of blanks to make that kind of game work, mostly in the fluff.  It is ***intentionally*** left up to you if Aetheric Resonance, et. al. works on the Fallen or not.  It is impossible for me to say 'yes or no', but only can tell you that you are intended to make that choice.

And when you make that choice, write it down - be consistent about it.

Answer (score 1):

**Can the Unchained detect the Fallen via Aetheric Resonance?**

Answer: **No**

Page 184 of the Demon: The Descent book describes Aetheric Resonance as follows:

> By expending a single point of Aether a demon can feel out Aether in the area around her for the remainder of the scene. Whenever a source of aetheric energy comes within the radius of her aetheric resonance, including a demon, she immediately becomes aware of the direction of the source and the quantity of Aether surrounding it.

Aetheric Resonance is based on Aether, which the Fallen do not have. In the last sentence of the description it mentions that powers that no not use Aether are not picked up by this ability. However, this is based on the concept of using Faith as-is. If you change the Fallen to be based on the God-Machine and therefore use Aether, they show up just fine (unless beholden to the same rules as an Unchained in Cover).

**Can the Fallen detect the Unchained via Supernatural Awareness?**

Answer: **Yes**

According to the Demon Translation Guide page 8-9 Supernatural Awareness works as follows:

> Demons can sense supernatural energies at work in their vicinity, regardless of the source. This perception stretches a number of miles equal to the demon’s permanent Faith. The demon’s player rolls Wits + Composure as an instant action. [...] This doesn’t tell the demon the nature of the supernatural energy or its purpose.

This lets them detect *any* supernatural abilities being used within range, regardless of source. While the Fallen cannot detect who or what used the supernatural ability they can sense it happening. This is not limited to any power source, or even the use of Essence of any kind (Demon Translation Guide page 9): if there's supernatural powers at work, a perceptive Fallen can detect what's going on. Even if you change if the Fallen run on Faith or Primum, they still keep this ability.